# Gather Data From User not sending task emails

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, tasks, designer-workflow

I have a workflow with a gather data from component. The email is sent to a user stored in current item: Assigned Manager field in the content type that triggers the workflow. When the user fills out the form the assigned manager is pulled entered using a people picker field.

The problem I'm having is that the email is sent inconsistently. It creates the task in the task list, but whether or not the email is sent is seemingly random.

I've checked the SMTP server logs and can't find any issues there and I can't find anything in the SharePoint logs either.

Thanks.

Edit: Failed to mention I had moved the workflow to a new server.

Comment: Workflow completed or error occure?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up recreating the workflow and that fixed the problem. I think there may have been some bad configuration from moving to a new server.